# Can I add a public property to a variable of an abstract class type?

Tags: c#

I am learning c# and implementing some OOPS concepts, I stumbled upon a question where they want me to define a class with a variable of type abstract class.
That is.

```
abstract class SummaryStrategy {
  public abstract void PrintSummary(List<int> numbers);
}

class DataAnalyser {
  private List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
  
  private SummaryStrategy _strategy;
}
```

Now they asked to add a public property to this private variable and I have no idea how to do that, I have read through the documentation.

I assumed that this strategy variable will contain string information but I can't do that here.
Any help is appreciated, I wish to learn this concept. An abstract class can be an interface but how does that help here?

Comment: I think you want `public SummaryStrategy => _strategy`.

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing?

Comment: The same as `public SummaryStrategy { get { return _strategy; } }` : It's a get-only property that returns the value of `_strategy`.

Comment: But I wish to store a string in strategy in a way, because I want to know what kind of strategy to apply. Or something along those lines so that I can use it in a if condition.

Comment: You cannot add a public property to a variable, what did they exactly ask?

Comment: This is the exact wording "Modify DataAnalyser to have a private variable "_strategy", that is of the type SummaryStrategy. Add a public property for this new private variable."

This is what has me on the ropes aha.

Comment: "Add a public property for this new private variable" horrible and horribly ambiguous. Who is torturing you this way again? Still the most probable guess is the one given in the first and third comments

Comment: I am in this course for C# I took and they gave me this question as part of a workbook and I am going nuts.

Comment: "Add a public property *for* a private variable" is somewhat ambiguous, but does make sense (and presumably means adding a public property with a getter that returns the value of the variable) - that's very different to adding a public property *to* a private variable, which is what your question requests, and which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Let's say I was to add a getter, I need a setter to this property as well because I want to store and change information in it. But I can't do that with an abstract class type, can I?

Comment: sure you can. You can do everything as in a normal class in an abstract one. Only difference is you cannot *instantiate* it. However as of your requirement you shouldn't add the property nor the field in the abstract class, but in your `DataAnalyser`-class.

Comment: How will I do that, especially in my scenario? Using the _strategy variable.

Comment: If I add the property in the DataAnalyser class, how will I access it using the strategy variable?

Comment: you don't access the property from the field, but other way round: the property accesses the field.

Comment: Can you give me an code example of how to do it?

Comment: see my answer! You already have everything you need.

Comment: I had to reload the page to see it, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that the wording of "a property to a variable" literally makes no sense, what it likely should mean is this:

> create a property that returns the value of that private field.

If we follow this assumption, you should create a public property in your `DataAnalyser`-class:

```
class DataAnalyser 
{
    private List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    private SummaryStrategy _strategy; 
    public SummaryStrategy 
    { 
        get { return _strategy; } 
        set { _stategy = value; } 
    }
}
```

You can read more about properties in [learning-section](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Also there are [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) that enable you to get rid of that pointless private backing-field and instead let you write this:

```
public SummaryStrategy { get; set; }
```

Comment: And it's not a "private variable", it's a "private field" or more generic "private member". And since we have auto-implemented properties (for over a decade already), we don't use private field-public property syntax anymore, unless something needs to happen on retrieval or assignment of the property.

Comment: The value ` set { _stategy = value; } ` in this can be a string?

Comment: @VanWilder eeehm, what? Your `_strategy`-field is of type `SummaryStrategy`, not `string`. So neither can `value` nor `_strategy` be a `string`.

Comment: I am also getting this error `invalid token '{' in class declaration`.

Comment: The whole of _strategy variable is to store info on what kind of strategy to apply I believe, but if it is an abstract class how will I ever store anything inside it?